Integrating External SQLX Models from GitHub Packages into Dataform Projects
I'm currently working with Dataform and facing a challenge regarding the integration of external SQLX models from a GitHub package into my Dataform project. Unlike dbt, which supports seamless package management and integration via packages.yml, Dataform seems to lack an equivalent feature for extending SQLX models directly from external sources.
Issue:
I've installed a package (specifically,bigquery-ml-pipeline from GitHub) which contains several SQLX files that I want to incorporate into my Dataform project. However, Dataform does not natively support referencing or executing these SQLX models directly from an external package like dbt does.
Has anyone successfully integrated external SQLX models into a Dataform project without resorting to manual file management?
Are there any best practices or tools within the Dataform ecosystem or third-party solutions that can facilitate this integration more seamlessly?
Any advice on automating the synchronization of external SQLX files into a Dataform project to keep them updated with the latest changes?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
